# Filter rows with common entry in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following mock data:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1=c("cat","dog","man","man","cat","cat"),
                 Col2=c("cat","dog","dog","dog","dog","cat"))
```

I want to filter out the rows which have the same name in both columns. In other words, I want to be left with unique names across each row.

So in my example, I will be left with an output like:

```
Col1 Col2
man dog
man dog
cat dog
```

Is there a tidyverse solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(Col1 != Col2)
  Col1 Col2
1  man  dog
2  man  dog
3  cat  dog
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Col1 != Col2]
```

Comment: Just to complete: `df %>% 
  filter(!(Col1 == Col2))`

Answer (score 2):

In `base`:

```
subset(df, Col1 != Col2)
```

or

```
df[with(df, Col1 != Col2),]
```

result:

```
#   Col1 Col2
# 3  man  dog
# 4  man  dog
# 5  cat  dog
```